# How to end program after results have been given python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know its something proper silly and easy but i can't work out how to end the program run after the results have been worked out and given on the last while statement, thanks in advance.

```
def main():
    pass

    Name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
    while True:
        HealthScore = int(raw_input("Enter your standardised health score: "))
        try:
            if 0 <= int(HealthScore) <= 100:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("The number must be in the range 0-100")

    while True:
        EconomicOutput = int(raw_input("Enter your standardised economic output score: "))
        try:
            if 0 <= int(EconomicOutput) <= 100:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("The number must be in the range 0-100")

    while True:
        Grade = (raw_input("Enter your standardised Grade: "))
        try:
            if Grade in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Grade is incorrect")

    while True:
        try:
            if Grade is 'A':
                print("congratulations, You meet the exceptional criteria")
                break
            elif EconomicOutput > 85 :
                print("congratulations, You meet the exceptional criteria")
                break
            elif EconomicOutput > 60 and HealthScore > 60 and Grade is 'B' or EconomicOutput > 60 and HealthScore > 60 and Grade is 'C':
                 print("congratulations, " + Name + " you have been selected.")
                 break
            else:
                print("Sorry, you do not meet the criteria")
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean "end the program"? Doesn't it end as it is right now? Also, don't test string equality using `is` because that's _object_ identity. Use `Grade == 'A'` instead.

Comment: okay will do thanks and no it says "indentation error : unexpected unindent" on the 2nd to last line @AndrasDeak

Comment: This question is very confusing. If your program doesn't even start because of a syntax error, why are you asking about "ending" it? Are you asking how to finish writing the `main` function?

Comment: I think there's a missing `except` block for your last `try` block.

Comment: sorry, that is what i mean, that will be the end of the main function the rest of the code works its just getting the right syntax to finish this function. p.s its my first day learning python  @Aran-Fey

Comment: In the future, please include the error message in your question. It makes your question easier to understand, and makes it easier for us to help you. And as others have already said, your last `try` statement is missing the `except` block.

Comment: You don't need syntax to end a function, if it runs out of code it will stop. To stop it before then use `break`.

Comment: Also, you use many `try` blocks in places where no error can occur. It seems that you mix up the `try... except` structure with `if... else`

Comment: ive got it to work guys thanks, ive accidentally added an extra try statement that was not needed

Comment: Technically, by the way. `break` terminates a loop. In my opinion `return` would have been clearer than `break` in this case, since with breaks one has to deduce that the function will return when the break terminates the loop.

Comment: @holdenweb thanks, im still learning all the different methods, first day learning ahah

Comment: If you're just learning python I strongly suggest learning python 3 instead. And finding a good tutorial. Have you read a tutorial yet? There are a lot of good and several bad ones out there.

Comment: The Stackoverflow Python chatroom has published a [list of tutorials](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) [disclaimer: my tutorials are listed].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sys.exit(1)

```
import sys
if Grade == 'A':
    print("congratulations, You meet the exceptional criteria")
    sys.exit(1)
```

and Done

At The Place of break; add sys.exit(1)
That Are Only An Example